# Slipstream updates into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, iso-image, slipstream

I'm trying to create a Windows 7 ISO that has all the updates included. The theory is that when Windows is installed, it included all the latest updates, so I don't need to reboot 5 times to install all the updates. It should speed up the installation dramatically.

To start, I've installed **Windows Update Downloader**. With this tool you can download all the current updates for a specific image (e.g. Windows 7 Enterprise, 32bit). The tool downloaded about 200 updates.

Afther downloading, I used dism to mount my Windows 7 ISO.

```
dism /image:C:\Mount /add-package /packagepath:PATH-TO-UPDATE
```

At this point, my command prompt is bussy for some time and I can see it adding the updates to the ISO. When completed, I commit the changes to the image and I recreate my bootable USB with the USB tool from Microsoft.

I install Windows, and bam: Windows still wants to do 170 updates. I've checked about 10 updates of the list that Windows want to do, and they are all in the updates I've downloaded with Windows Update Downloader.

- Updates are English, Windows Installation is English
- I've downloaded the 32bit updates for the 32bit version of Windows
- I've tried adding the updates with RT7Lite, same problem
- I'm using an USB to boot
- I'm using autounattend.xml to speed up my installation

I'm struggling with this problem for days now. I've created +10 images, but they all give the same problem.

Comment: check the CBS.log if the integration of the updates was successful or not.

Comment: it looks like McAfee on my computer blocked something when using the DISM command. I've disabled McAfee, tested with some updates and it worked. I'm now trying this with all my updates.

Comment: ok, post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from *Jente*

> it looks like McAfee on my computer blocked something when using the
>   DISM command. I've disabled McAfee, tested with some updates and it
>   worked. I'm now trying this with all my updates.

Here is the KB Article: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB76867